# Encountering a `None Type` in Tkinter-based Blackjack game when trying to access an attribute

Tags: python, tkinter, game-development

Community,

I am working on a Blackjack game using Tkinter in Python, and I'm encountering a couple of issues that I'm struggling to resolve. I appreciate any insights or suggestions you can provide.

Dealer's Cards Not Hidden:
The first issue I'm facing is related to the visibility of the dealer's cards. In the game, when the dealer's cards are initially displayed, one card should be hidden (face-down) while the other is shown (face-up). However, in my implementation, all of the dealer's cards are visible from the beginning. I'm not sure how to correctly implement the hiding of one card until the player stands, furthermore on "Stand" it doesn't update the dealers cards, it only displays if I win or lose, whilst the hit method works as intended.

Empty Deck Displayed:
The second issue I'm experiencing is related to the deck. After a few rounds of the game, when I click the "Stand" button, the remaining cards label shows that the deck is empty. Additionally, the dealer and player hands are updated with new cards, but instead of drawing from a new deck, it seems to pop all the cards out at once, resulting in an empty deck. I suspect this is related to how I handle deck initialization or the draw mechanism.

Since I am not sure, where exactly my issue lies, I will provide you with the full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.rank} of {self.suit}"

    def value(self):
        if self.rank.isdigit():
            return int(self.rank)
        elif self.rank in ['J', 'Q', 'K']:
            return 10
        elif self.rank == 'A':
            return 11

class Deck:
    def __init__(self, num_decks):
        self.num_decks = num_decks
        self.cards = []
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.cards = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in ['Hearts', 'Spades', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds']
                        for rank in ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']]
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def draw(self):
        if len(self.cards) > 0:
            return self.cards.pop()
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Empty Deck")

class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def add_card(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def calculate_value(self):
        total_value = sum(card.value() for card in self.cards)
        num_aces = sum(1 for card in self.cards if card.rank == 'A')

        while total_value > 21 and num_aces > 0:
            total_value -= 10
            num_aces -= 1

        return total_value

class BlackjackGame:
    def __init__(self, num_decks):
        self.deck = Deck(num_decks)
        self.player_hand = Hand()
        self.dealer_hand = Hand()

        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("BLACKJACK")
        self.window.config()

        self.player_label = tk.Label(self.window, text="Player's cards:")
        self.player_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.player_cards_label = tk.Label(self.window, text='', font=("Courier", 30))
        self.player_cards_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.dealer_label = tk.Label(self.window, text="Dealer's cards:")
        self.dealer_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.dealer_cards_label = tk.Label(self.window, text='', font=("Courier", 30))
        self.dealer_cards_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.message_label = tk.Label(self.window, text='')
        self.message_label.grid(row=4, column=0)

        self.remaining_cards_label = tk.Label(self.window, text='', font=('Courier', 20))
        self.remaining_cards_label.grid(row=5, column=0)

        self.sum_value_label = tk.Label(self.window, text='', font=('Courier', 20))
        self.sum_value_label.grid(row=6, column=0)

        self.hit_button = tk.Button(self.window, text="Hit", command=self.hit)
        self.hit_button.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=(10, 0), padx=10)  # Top padding

        self.deal_button = tk.Button(self.window, text="Deal", command=self.new_round)
        self.deal_button.grid(row=8, column=0, pady=10)  # Padding between buttons

        self.stand_button = tk.Button(self.window, text="Stand", command=self.stand)
        self.stand_button.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=10)

        self.card_images = {
        'Hearts': {'A': ' ♥A ', '2': ' ♥2 ', '3': ' ♥3 ', '4': ' ♥4 ', '5': ' ♥5 ', '6': ' ♥6 ',
               '7': ' ♥7 ', '8': ' ♥8 ', '9': ' ♥9 ', '10': '♥10', 'J': ' ♥J ', 'Q': ' ♥Q ',
               'K': ' ♥K '},
    'Diamonds': {'A': ' ♦A ', '2': ' ♦2 ', '3': ' ♦3 ', '4': ' ♦4 ', '5': ' ♦5 ', '6': ' ♦6 ',
                 '7': ' ♦7 ', '8': ' ♦8 ', '9': ' ♦9 ', '10': '♦10', 'J': ' ♦J ', 'Q': ' ♦Q ',
                 'K': ' ♦K '},
    'Clubs': {'A': ' ♣A ', '2': ' ♣2 ', '3': ' ♣3 ', '4': ' ♣4 ', '5': ' ♣5 ', '6': ' ♣6 ',
              '7': ' ♣7 ', '8': ' ♣8 ', '9': ' ♣9 ', '10': '♣10', 'J': ' ♣J ', 'Q': ' ♣Q ',
              'K': ' ♣K '},
    'Spades': {'A': ' ♠A ', '2': ' ♠2 ', '3': ' ♠3 ', '4': ' ♠4 ', '5': ' ♠5 ', '6': ' ♠6 ',
               '7': ' ♠7 ', '8': ' ♠8 ', '9': ' ♠9 ', '10': '♠10', 'J': ' ♠J ', 'Q': ' ♠Q ',
               'K': ' ♠K '}
        }

        self.window.title("BLACKJACK")
        self.window.mainloop()

    def start(self):
        self.deck.reset()
        self.player_hand = Hand()
        self.dealer_hand = Hand()
        self.deal_cards()
        self.update_ui()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def deal_cards(self):
        self.player_hand.add_card(self.deck.draw())
        self.dealer_hand.add_card(self.deck.draw())
        self.player_hand.add_card(self.deck.draw())
        self.dealer_hand.add_card(self.deck.draw())
        #self.show_dealer_cards(reveal_card=False)

    def hit(self):
        self.player_hand.add_card(self.deck.draw())
        self.update_ui()

        if self.player_hand.calculate_value() > 21:
            self.message_label.config(text="Player busted!")
            self.hit_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
            self.stand_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
            self.show_dealer_cards(reveal_card=True)
        elif self.player_hand.calculate_value() == 21:
            self.message_label.config(text='Blackjack! Player wins.')
            self.hit_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
            self.stand_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

    def stand(self):
        self.update_ui()

        while self.dealer_hand.calculate_value() > 17:
            self.dealer_hand.add_card(self.deck.draw())
            self.update_ui()
        self.update_ui()

        player_value = self.player_hand.calculate_value()
        dealer_value = self.dealer_hand.calculate_value()

        if dealer_value > 21:
            self.message_label.config(text='Dealer busts, you win!')
            self.update_ui()
        elif dealer_value < player_value:
            self.message_label.config(text='You win!')
            self.update_ui()
        elif dealer_value > player_value:
            self.message_label.config(text='You lose.')
            self.update_ui()

        self.hit_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.stand_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.update_ui()

    def show_dealer_cards(self, reveal_card=False):
        cards = self.dealer_hand.cards
        if reveal_card:
            self.dealer_cards_label.config(text=' '.join(self.card_images[card.suit][card.rank] for card in cards))
        else:
            self.dealer_cards_label.config(text=self.card_images[cards[0].suit][cards[0].rank] + ' ?' * (len(cards)-1))

    def update_ui(self):
        player_cards = self.player_hand.cards
        dealer_cards = self.dealer_hand.cards

        self.player_cards_label.config(text=' '.join(self.card_images[card.suit][card.rank] for card in player_cards))
        self.dealer_cards_label.config(text=' '.join(self.card_images[card.suit][card.rank] for card in dealer_cards))

        self.remaining_cards_label.config(text=f"Remaining Cards : {len(self.deck.cards)}")
        self.sum_value_label.config(text=f"Value Player Cards: {self.player_hand.calculate_value()} Value Dealer Cards: {self.dealer_hand.calculate_value()}")

    def new_round(self):
        self.message_label.config(text='')
        self.hit_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.stand_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.player_cards_label.config(text='')
        self.dealer_cards_label.config(text='')

        self.player_hand = Hand()
        self.dealer_hand = Hand()
        self.deal_cards()
        self.update_ui()


game = BlackjackGame(num_decks=6)
game.start()
```

Interestingly enough, the error message I'm provided with closing the game is only distantly related to the descripted problems. As I'm quite new to programming and completely new to StackOverflow, I will again provide you with the full error, I do hope you don't mind:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "game.py", line 147, in stand
    self.update_ui()
  File "game.py", line 179, in update_ui
    self.dealer_cards_label.config(text=' '.join(self.card_images[card.suit][card.rank] for card in dealer_cards))
  File "game.py", line 179, in <genexpr>
    self.dealer_cards_label.config(text=' '.join(self.card_images[card.suit][card.rank] for card in dealer_cards))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'suit'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 198, in <module>
    game.start()
  File "game.py", line 118, in start
    self.update_ui()
  File "game.py", line 178, in update_ui
    self.player_cards_label.config(text=' '.join(self.card_images[card.suit][card.rank] for card in player_cards))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1636, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!label2"

***Repl Closed***
```

Again, any help or insight will be greatly appreciated. I understand my code will be a bit of a mess to search through, but I thought this way it would be easier to communicate my problem.

When troubleshooting, this is what I already tried:

Firstly adressing the issue of hiding the Dealer's crad:

I attempted to hide one of the dealer's cards by using the show_dealer_cards method and passing a parameter reveal_card to control the visibility.
I expected that only one dealer card should be visible at the beginning, with the other card hidden.
Actual Outcome: Both of the dealer's cards are visible from the start, and the hidden card is not being correctly displayed.

Then adressing the issue of the empty Deck:

I tried to ensure that the deck remains intact and functioning throughout the game, so I implemented the reset method in the Deck class to regenerate the deck with all the cards.
I used the draw method to simulate drawing a card from the deck by popping the top card from the list of cards.
I expected or rather hoped that the deck should be properly reset, and each draw should remove a card from the deck while keeping the remaining cards intact.
Actual Outcome: After a few rounds, when the "Stand" button is clicked, the remaining cards label shows that the deck is empty. Additionally, instead of drawing cards from the deck, all the cards seem to pop out at once, resulting in an empty deck.
These are the main attempts I made to address the issues, but they did not produce the expected outcomes. I'm seeking help on how to correctly hide the dealer's cards and ensure the deck remains intact throughout the game.

Again thank you for your help and either way, have a good day!

Comment: Still persisted line 179 suit is not defined. The problem is I added total 25.